# Is conditional binding in swift pass by value or reference?

Tags: swift

I've been having some issues with conditional binding returning an invalid (but non-nil) object from the watch accelerometer. I was thinking maybe making a copy of the object could help the problem, but I wasn't sure if that was already occurring. If I use code such as:

```
if let data = recorder.accelerometerData(from: startDate, to: endDate){...}
```

is this already creating a copy of the CMSensorDataList object or am I simply getting a reference to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just depends upon whether the type wrapped by the optional was a value type or reference type. If reference type, it's obviously pass by reference. If value type, it's copied (unless CoW, copy-on-write, in which case it's copied if and when it's mutated).

In this case, [`CMSensorDataList`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmsensordatalist) is a class, so it's a reference to that instance, not a copy of it.